# Firebase: Add/Edit/View documents just by users in a specific group

Tags: firebase

I want to create a data collection in my firebase database, which can only be accessed by users in a specific group.

I already searched for some roles & rights stuff, but I found no fitting information.

Is there a built-in feature in firebase to do that?
Otherwise I would add a collection with the group name and add users as document (with document id = user id). Then I would configure the read and write access for protected collection just for users which has a corresponding document in the related group collection.

T